# Call servlet on window.open in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

How can I call servlet using `window.open()`?

My code is:

```
onclick='window.open("/PDFServlet", "popupWindowName", 
  "dependent=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=1, toolbar=no,width800,height=600")'
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code ?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with jsp and servlets? Both the question and the answer is only related to jsf and javascript as far as I can understand.

Comment: Just change `"/PDFServlet"` to something like `"/PDFServlet/page.jsp"` to open JavaServr page called "page.jsp" linking to a folder will usually fail due to security reasons as it will try to browse that folder on the server.

Comment: @Shadow: it's perfectly valid to map a servlet on a "folder" URL (a pretty URL). The URL at whole is apparently plain invalid (404 and on) or the OP just didn't implement `doGet()` method properly. Yet he didn't mention what exactly went wrong so giving a good answer is relatively hard.

Comment: @Balus thanks, wasn't aware of the mapping option. Guess we now wait for the OP...

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if your application is deployed as the `ROOT` context. If not, you have to specify `/context/PDFServlet/`